# 'iw dev XYZ interface add' is not using the provided 'addr' option

Tags: linux, linux-networking, devices

The title says it all. I am running:

```
sudo iw dev wlp2s0 interface add my_interface type managed addr 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
```

Then, upon checking `iw my_interface info` I see a completely different address.